# Email problem with newly added SharePoint 2013 frontend server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, email

I have a SharePoint2013 farm with 1 application (AP1), 1 frontend (FE1) and 1 database (DB1) server and I've added a new frontend server (FE2) to this farm. Everything works perfect except SPD worflow e-mails. Before adding new frontend server, all e-mails were working perfect but after adding this frontend server sometimes some e-mails are not sending. I have F5 load balancer in front of the FE1 and FE2 and sticky sessions enabled and also new FE2 have permission on our relay server. I did not find anything on ULS logs but still searching. What am I doing wrong? Is there anything else to do when adding new FE to farm?

Edit: I tried sending e-mail using following scripts.

```
$email = "user@example.com"
$subject = "Email through FE"
$body = "Message body. "

$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite "http://myspapp"
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($web,0,0,$email,$subject,$body)
$web.Dispose()
```

1 -> FE1 and FE2 are up. Ran script 3 times from FE2 server and ULS logs says 3 e-mails successfully sent but only 2 e-mails I received.

2 --> FE1 up and FE2 down. Ran script 3 times and I received 3 e-mails as expected.

3 --> FE2 up and FE1 down. Ran script 3 times and I received 3 e-mails as expected.

4 --> FE1 up and FE2 up. Ran script 3 times and I received 1 e-mail.

Can F5 load balancer cause such problem? Sticky sessions enabled on F5 but is there any other configuration for SharePoint? Are *Affinity* and *Persistence* configuration mode for F5 sticky sessions and can they be enable or disable? I found [this](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/) for difference between affinity and persistence but I don't know anything about F5 and how to do or what to tell F5 admins for this configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not so SharePoint related, but you maybe need to add the new servers IP to be allowed to use your mailserver?

Comment: You could try to use powershell on the new server and use the cmdlet send-mailmessage to see if it is allowed for outgoing emails. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried following cmdlet to send email using PowerShell ISE at FE1,FE2 and AP1 servers at the farm and they sended successfully. All servers are allowed to send email using relay.


    Send-MailMessage -To "Receiver <user@example.com>" -From "Sender <sender@exapmle2.com>" -Subject "Test mail AP" -SmtpServer <RelayServerIP> -Credential domain\farmadmin

Comment: Could it be any services that are not enabled on the new server? Compare the services running on your working and non working server, both the MS services and SharePoint Services.

Comment: In central admin, Old server (FE1) and new server (FE2) has same services running but FE1 has SQL Server Reporting Services Service and FE2 not. Is this service important to sending SPD workflow emails? Also checked services.msc and same services are running.

Comment: No, reporting services is a BI related component and have nothing to do with the email. Could it be that the loadbalancer are balancing the actual request to send emails so it get split up and no server will send it because it does not how to handle an incomplete request? I had similar issues with load balancing before.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is not able to perform SMTP-Authentication to send outgoing E-Mails. It always connects as anonymous to your SMTP-Server (e.g. Exchange).

You already tried to send a testmail via PowerShell, but you used the '-Credential' switch. This will perform a SMTP-Authentication. So your testing is not accurate.

Please check your SMTP-Server again. The IP-Address of your new FrontEnd-Server needs to be able to send anonymous E-Mails . On an Exchange-System this setting is configured in the "Receive Connector".

Comment: Actually, system admins controlled SMTP server configuration again and again. E-mails working and not working from time to time. Such as, I send 2 e-mails in SPD workflow and I receive only one e-mail. We use F5 with round robin so I guess F5 sends one request to FE1 and other request to FE2 even for same workflow.